# Установка цвета фона QPalette в QTextEdit

Tags: python, pyqt5, qt-designer, qtextedit, qpalette

Почему когда я устанавливаю цвет для `QTextEdit`:

```
self.MainTextEdit.setPalette(QtGui.QPalette(
    QColor(
        self.oldEFColor[0], 
        self.oldEFColor[1], 
        self.oldEFColor[2], 
        self.oldEFColor[3]
    )
))
```

Устанавливается нужный цвет только тогда, когда выбираешь черный

**P.S.**

```
self.oldEFColor[r, g, b, a]
```

**UPD :**

До того, как я пытаюсь установить цвет :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Далее пытаюсь применить цвет :

```
color = QtWidgets.QColorDialog.getColor(QColor(self.oldEFColor[0], self.oldEFColor[1], self.oldEFColor[2], self.oldEFColor[3]), self)
          if color.isValid():
            self.oldEFColor = color.getRgb()
            
  self.MainTextEdit.setPalette(QtGui.QPalette(QColor(self.oldEFColor[0],self.oldEFColor[1], self.oldEFColor[2], self.oldEFColor[3])))  

                                                          
   self.MainTextEditLabel.setAutoFillBackground(True)
```

Допустим красный :

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Опубликуйте минимально-воспроизводимый пример, который демонстрирует проблему.

Comment: Дополнил, если вы об этом

Answer (score 4):

я вас просил опубликуйте минимально-воспроизводимый пример! Надеюсь, что в следующий раз вы это будете делать.

Распаковывать надо так:

```
QtGui.QColor(*oldEFColor)
```

---

```
from PyQt5 import QtWidgets, QtGui

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QtWidgets.QApplication([])

    frame = QtWidgets.QFrame()
    frame.setFrameShape(QtWidgets.QFrame.Box)
    frame.setLineWidth(3)
    frame.setAutoFillBackground(True)                                        #

    oldEFColor = [155, 110, 255, 255]
    color = QtWidgets.QColorDialog.getColor(
        QtGui.QColor(oldEFColor[0], oldEFColor[1], oldEFColor[2], oldEFColor[3])) 
    if color.isValid(): 
        oldEFColor = color.getRgb()
    print( oldEFColor )   

    palette = frame.palette()
    palette.setBrush(QtGui.QPalette.Background, QtGui.QColor(*oldEFColor))     # <<<-----< *oldEFColor
    frame.setPalette(palette)

    widget = QtWidgets.QWidget()
    w_layout = QtWidgets.QVBoxLayout(widget)
    w_layout.addWidget(frame)

    widget.resize(200, 200)
    widget.show()
    app.exec_()
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: @FOX_i_K что не так?